# .htacess rewrite to truncate links with common mistakes?

Tags: .htaccess

Everyone who have tried to search through error_log files from large websites got lots of links like these bellow due to people who have screwd up some html in third part sites or blogs...

```
File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/materias/137.html'http://...
File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/materias/137.html http://...
File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/materias/137.html/mydomain...
```

The problem is some extra chars after the .html...

Its easy to guess the correct url in each case... we just have to truncate the url after the ".html".

Is it possible with `.htaccess` to rewrite these problematic urls to the correct syntax?

Just eliminating everything after the .

html? And avoiding messing up with url queries in dynamic urls?

Here's what I would like to do ...

Replace `".html "` with `".html#"`

Replace `".html'"` with `".html#"`

Replace `".html/"` with `".html#"`

As everything after the `#` will be just ignored...

Any simple way to do that with .htaccess?

Comment: It would be best if updated your question with the name of the Web Server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Regex:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html(.*)$    $1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This `RedirectMatch` rule should work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+?\.html).+$ $1
```